# How to distinguish pointer up inside button vs drag-out

Tags: unity, c#, input, events, unity-ui

I am making a unity mobile game, I have a simple scene and a canvas with a few buttons and these buttons have scripts that detect if the button was pressed and released. Here is the code for doing this:

```
public class InteractiveButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{ 
      
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //do something
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine as when i press the button the down event gets triggered as expected, but if i keep my finger pressed and drag my fingers off the bounds of the button and let go the `OnPointerUp` method still gets called as if I let my finger go on the button.

So how can I detect if the player lets go out of the buttons bounds?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) and [IPointerExitHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerExitHandler.html) ?